# Rstudio Won't Let Me Commit

Tags: github, rstudio, commit

How do I commit my material in Rstudio?  About two months ago I cloned a svn to my Rstudio, via Github.  I was able to commit initially, but I can’t anymore.  After I committed, I decided I wanted to restart and create a new project.  So I once again cloned the svn and made a new project, so I could do my project from scratch.  However, after I finished I was left with the inability to commit my work to Github.  After asking around I was told that it might have been because I did not fork it a second time (is this true?).

How do I commit my work to Github?  Do I start over and copy my code and documents into a new R project (and hope it works), or is there some way for me to manually link my project to Github from the assignment I already completed?  Thank you to anyone who answers.  :)

Sincerely,

Devan

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my issue by doing the following.

Step 1: Locate where your Rstudio files are located on your computer.

Step 2: Copy and paste all your updated files (rmd, graphs, etc.) from your new folder into the original folder you were able to commit with originally.

Step 3: Optional, delete all of your old files in the original folder.

Step 4: Commit and push/pull your new files to Github from your original folder.

I hope this helps someone.  Good luck!